# New to Haskell and there is unexpected '='

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I am totally new to Haskell and try to follow the script in lecture notes.
I created a file called lecture.hs

```
root (a, b, c) = ((-b -r)/e, (-b + r)/e))
 where d = b*b - 4*a*c
       r = sqrt d
       e = 2*a
```

when I load this file to hugs it shows

```
ERROR "lecture.hs":3 - Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')
```

and when I load it to ghci it shows

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( lecture.hs, interpreted )

lecture.hs:3:14: parse error on input `='
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: There is an extra parenthesis at the end of the first line.

Comment: I am sorry it was a typo here. Without the extra parenthesis there is still the same error message.

Comment: Strange; after a copy-paste (to vim) your snippet ran just fine here. Are you using tabs to indent your code? If so, that might be the issue (tabs and significant whitespace do not mix well).

Comment: I just tried to retype all code with space only and it works. So is that in haskell I can only use pure tab or pure space or space only?

Comment: @user2891198 you don't have to do it either way, but you do have to be consistent within each definition. It's easiest to use only spaces.

Comment: @user2891198 Yes, you can use either only tabs, or only spaces. Whitespace is significant in Haskell, and a tab can represent a variable number of spaces, so tabs are ambiguous. My advice is to never use tabs and always use spaces.

Comment: @user2891198 While tabs work, using spaces is recommended in Haskell since we Haskell programmers rarely "indent" code in the same sense that you do in other languages. In Haskell, you rarely talk about "blocks of code." Rather, you align arguments to functions with each other, and it is undisputed that spaces are better for alignment.

Comment: The rule in Haskell is that a tab is equivalent to spacing up to the next indentation level that is a multiple of 8 characters.  Unless your editor is set up to use the exact same rule, it can easily break. And even if it is, the program can confuse other readers who don't have the right setup. So it's simplest to always use spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pasted here, your snippet is syntactically valid. In any case, the following is sure to work:

```
root (a, b, c) = ((-b -r)/e, (-b + r)/e)
    where
    d = b*b - 4*a*c
    r = sqrt d
    e = 2*a
```

Naturally, indentation style is to a significant extent a personal choice. I like placing `where` in a separate line because that way I can indent the code predictably in four space steps. Whatever style you choose, don't use tabs to indent, as that leads to a lot of confusion.